More errors after upgrade to SDK 1.13
After solving frame-support-procedureal and pined some crates still have build issues for my SDK 1.13 upgrade. This time it is a duplicate definition:
  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `memchr` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/simson/nodle/chain/target/debug/wbuild/runtime-eden/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-272dc3de87a92110.rmeta
    = note: second definition in `std` loaded from /home/simson/nodle/chain/target/debug/wbuild/runtime-eden/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libstd-392857d4fb9add68.rmeta

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0152`.
  error: could not compile `frame-support` (lib) due to 1 previous error
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...


This is usually an issue with your features. This can be solved by using a combination of Polkadot SDK Version Manager and Zepter

I was having the same issue and found, by looking at the Cargo.lock, that the serde_json package was introducing the memchr dependency. I fixed it by downgrading the version:
cargo update -p serde_json --precise 1.0.120

